# Remapping $ to another character in vimrc

Tags: vim, editor

I'd like to remap dollar sign as the key for moving to the end of the line. I would prefer € sign (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> on my native keyboard which is in my opinion more ergonomic than <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> resulting in $) instead.

I've tried

```
inoremap € $
```

and

```
inoremap € <$>
```

But either one is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without the `i`, which creates a mapping in the `insert` mode:

```
noremap € $
```

If you want to map `€` in `insert` mode as well, just add `<c-o>` in your mapping:

```
noremap € $
inoremap € <c-o>$
```

`<c-o>` lets you leave the `insert` mode to `normal` mode just for one command.

Comment: It works for me... Doest it work if you map temporarly a standard key, let's say `noremap A $` ?

Comment: yolenoyer: Got it working too, I had a trailing space after the dollar sign which moved cursor to the next line. Thank you!